# Is there a way to the last position of a pipe other than reading until there is nothing left?

Tags: c, linux, posix, pipe

Current way:

```
while(read(pipe, input, sizeof(input))>0);
```

Is there a better one with seeking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pipes on computers are like pipes in the "real" world... Data flows from one end to the other, and once it's gone from the pipe there is no getting it back. And like a real pipe there is no knowing when the flow will stop, so there is no meaning to try and find the end of the flow before it actually ends.

Answer (score 2):

No, you can't seek in pipes. You'll have to read through it.

Your code should handle cases where read returns -1 though, and not just assume it's properly positioned when the loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

You can splice( 2 ) into /dev/null to consume all of the data, but it's a tough argument that this is "better".

Comment: There is also a related `tee(2)` system call - which I never used.

Answer (score 0):

You also could close the readable end of the pipe prematurely. But if the writer end code don't handle that case (by e.g. calling `poll` or `select` before writing), it will get a `SIGPIPE` signal.